# What´s the opposite of opening and closing tags in {PHP}?

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $realm = 'Restricted area';

    //user => password
    $users = array('admin' => 'mypass', 'guest' => 'guest');


    if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
           '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');

    die('Text to send if user hits Cancel button');
    }


    // analyze the PHP_AUTH_DIGEST variable
    if (!($data = http_digest_parse($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) ||
    !isset($users[$data['username']]))
    die("?><?php(8)");


    // generate the valid response
    $A1 = md5($data['username'] . ':' . $realm . ':' . $users[$data['username']]);
    $A2 = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].':'.$data['uri']);
    $valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$data['nonce'].':'.$data['nc'].':'.$data['cnonce'].':'.$data['qop'].':'.$A2);

    if ($data['response'] != $valid_response)
    die('Wrong Credentials!');

    // ok, valid username & password
    echo('?><?php(8)');
    # Jag har druckit för mycket alkohol

    // function to parse the http auth header
    function http_digest_parse($txt)
    {
    // protect against missing data
    $needed_parts = array('nonce'=>1, 'nc'=>1, 'cnonce'=>1, 'qop'=>1, 'username'=>1, 'uri'=>1, 'response'=>1);
    $data = array();
    $keys = implode('|', array_keys($needed_parts));

    preg_match_all('@(' . $keys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        $data[$m[1]] = $m[3] ? $m[3] : $m[4];
        unset($needed_parts[$m[1]]);
    }

    return $needed_parts ? false : $data;
    }?>
```

This is the parts `?><?php(8)` where as I need help! I want the PHP tags to be THE OPPOSITE OF the usual opening-and-closing tags!! Please help!

Comment: Note that the code between 'Restricted area' is the most insufficient way to include your code

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is `<?php(8)` supposed to mean? I don't think you can put a version number there.

Comment: @Barmar Its' just for testing purposes. I'm trying to test the neds of the string to get the right rresult! :)

Comment: What is the stuff about aunt lara and Invidia supposed to mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "test the ends of the string"? Sending `<?php` to the browser won't have any effect, the browser doesn't parse PHP.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean, what you're trying to achieve, or what the problem is. See [ask] for some guidance, and try again, remembering that we can't read your mind. You'll need to explain more clearly. Thanks